# Update column with same id but different record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

`$int_code, $dial_code, $phone1` I am getting two value, I want to update field with these record on behalf of `advert_id = 3083609`

using  php

```
UPDATE subscr_number
SET int_code= $int_code[$i]
  , dial_code=$dial_code[$i]
  , phone_no=$phone1[$i]
WHERE advert_id=3083609
```

advert id    int_code    dial_code   phone_no

3083609

3083609

I want to update it like i.e.

advert id    int_code    dial_code   phone_no

3083609        123            11       9595959

3083609        256            943       9292292

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: I have updated it please check.

Comment: I don't think you need a UPDATE; rather a INSERT.

Comment: and suppose I have to update phone_no column like 9595959 then w.r.t 3083609